# Singleton DAO instance keeps old closed session between HTTP transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, singleton, dao

I'm trying to implement the "One-session-per-http-request" pattern with Hibernate, and it works for the 1st request : The servlet's doGet() method opens the session, gets some stuff, and closes the session.

But when I refresh the browser, My DAO Singleton instance (whose constructor gets the session from the SessionFactory) gets called a second time, but still uses the old session object (the singleton constructor is NOT called again). I then obtain a "Session is closed" error.

I guess that the singleton instance must be kept in cache between HTTP requests, so : How can I get the DAO singleton constructor called again ? (or another elegant solution to have the fresh SessionFactory session object ?)

Thank you very much

The servlet :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        // Gets the session, eventually creates one
        Session s = HibernateUtil.currentSession();

        // Gets data from singleton DAO instance
        MySingletonDAO o = MySingletonDAO.getInstance();
        List<Stuff> stuff = o.getAllTheStuff();

        // send it to the view
        request.setAttribute("foo",stuff);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(vue);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
             /*  error handling blah blah */
    finally {
        // closing the session
        HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }
```

MySingletonDAO.java :

```
public class MySingletonDAO {
    // Usual singleton syntax
    private static MySingletonDAO INSTANCE = new MySingletonDAO();
    public static MySingletonDAO getInstance() { return INSTANCE;}

    private Session session;

    private MySingletonDAO() {
        session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
        System.out.println("This constructor is called only on the first HTTP transaction");
    }

    public List<Stuff> getAllTheStuff() {
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("FROM StuffDBTable");
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return (List<Stuff>) q.list();
        }
    }
}
```

A classical thread-safe HibernateUtil.java :

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public static final ThreadLocal session = new ThreadLocal();

    static {
        try {
            // Creates the SessionFactory
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Conf problem : "+ he.getMessage(), he);
        }
    }


    public static Session currentSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session s = (Session) session.get();
        // Opens a new Session, if this Thread has none
        if (s == null || !s.isOpen() ) {
            s = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.set(s);
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session s = (Session) session.get();
        session.set(null);
        if (s != null)
            s.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for doesn't make sense: if the constructor of the singleton was called at each request, it wouldn't be a singleton anymore. The session is indeed closed at the end of the request, but the DAO keeps a reference to the session, instead of getting it from your util class every time it's called.

Your DAO code should be

```
public class MySingletonDAO {
    private static MySingletonDAO INSTANCE = new MySingletonDAO();
    public static MySingletonDAO getInstance() { return INSTANCE;}

    private MySingletonDAO() {
    }

    public List<Stuff> getAllTheStuff() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Query q = session.createQuery("FROM StuffDBTable");
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return (List<Stuff>) q.list();
        }
    }
}
```

That said, transactions should be handled declaratively, and should be handled at the service layer rather than the DAO layer: a transaction typically uses deveral DAOs, the entities returned by the DAO should stay managed, and all the accesses and modifications made to these entities should be made inside the transaction.

I strongly recommend using a Java EE container, or Spring, to handle the transactions and the session handling for you. You should also use the standard JPA API rather than the proprietary Hibernate API.

Comment: Service Layer is the clue I needed, I couldn't see why the Model had to manage transactions and sessions.
If I get your helpful directions correctly (after a bit of browsing), it acts as an  intermediary layer between the Servlet and the DAO methods, to manage secondary concerns like transactions, errors, and returned objects handling.
If I may, for future readers, suggest this link  which helped me getting the big picture :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658090.aspx